# Salesforce Custom Login and registration using apex

Tags: salesforce

I am working on developing custom salesforce app (Survey app) in salesforce, things so far i have done are.
Add survey 
Add Survey Questions
Making the survey Link Public.
Take Survey
Survey Result etc.

Public Survey Link is here:
https://lycore-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/TakeSurvey?id=a012800000ISuXc

Now i need to know that how can i Create a custom Login and Custom registration, so, before taking the survey, users could login or Register themselves into salesforce. I need the way to Login or register. Thanks.

Comment: can you help me on this ? @chiz

Comment: :-) Actually, no. I was wondering myself how to do this. I assume, you need to create  a Site withing your org. Then you should manage login/registration user on your Visualforce page (or html). Maybe SF has smoother way to do this. I haven't checked that yet.

Comment: Thank you :) . I have already created the site, i m pretty sure we can do this , but needs to find a proper way.
I also manage to login or register user through "customer portal Manger", but the issue is i cannot access "Custom objects".

Login page:
https://lycore-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/SiteLogin
https://lycore-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/SiteRegister

Comment: Check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5784/portal-users-not-able-to-access-custom-object